# Mercurial and Subversion: changing, committing, pulling from SVN, pushing, "Sorry, can't find svn parent of a merge revision."

Tags: svn, mercurial, hgsubversion, hgsvn

I've pulled the Subversion repository into a local Hg repository while at work. At home, I fixed some stuff, committed into my local Hg repository, and upon coming to work I did a pull and an update.

```
$ hg pull
$ hg update
```

I needed to merge, so I did that.

```
$ hg merge
```

However, when I tried pushing:

```
$ hg push
abort: Sorry, can't find svn parent of a merge revision."
```

What mistake did I make in the workflow? What can I do to avoid the issue in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the sequence is

```
hg pull 
hg up # update the repo to the head 
hg rebase --svn # rebase your_head onto svn
hg push
```

When you want to push the changes directly into svn, you first pull the latest changes from svn, then rebase your changes to the svn HEAD and push them back.

[Edit : These commands are not available as a part of standard hg command]

You will need to install hgsubversion Extension.

- http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/overview
- http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/hgsubversion.html
- http://blog.red-bean.com/sussman/?p=116
- http://code.google.com/p/hgsubversion/
- http://farmdev.com/thoughts/64/try-out-the-mercurial-subversion-extension-hg-svn-on-mac-os-x/
- http://cecinestpasun.com/entries/getting-hgsubversion-work-under-osx/

Comment: I guess I should not have used "hg merge", despite Mercurial's suggestion. Also, "hg push " does not seem to accept the --svn argument, so you may want to edit the answer, for other people's use. Also, "hg up" seems to be able to be standalone, without your_head argument.

Comment: @Ivan Vučica : I assumed that you have hgsubversion installed. A kick on my head, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: I do have hgsubversion or else I would not be able to pull a Subversion repo :-) I'm just saying that "push" does not support --svn, and "up" does not require the head argument. You may want to revise the answer.